# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException while executing query in DB2

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I have the following piece of code:
(basically it's a JAVA-DB2 Connectivity test program)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection; 
import java.sql.DriverManager; 
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class TestDB22
{
     public static void main(String  rgs[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException 
     { 
        Class.forName("COM.ibm.db2os390.sqlj.jdbc.DB2SQLJDriver");
        Connection  con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:rajdb","db2admin","db2admin"); 
        System. out .println( "From TestDB22, connection obtained " );

        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery( "select * from libids" ); 
        while( rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs . getString(2));

        }

     } 
}
```

I get the following error:

> From TestDB22, connection obtained
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>     at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)    at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:103)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.a(ab.java:151)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.uw.UWReply.b(UWReply.java:62)     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.c(ab.java:243)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.c(ab.java:354)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.ab.v(ab.java:1139)     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.c(db.java:52)   at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.c(t.java:44)     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.i(sb.java:147)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.gb(km.java:1985)    at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.a(km.java:2866)     at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.a(km.java:628)  at
>   com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.km.executeQuery(km.java:612)   at
>   TestDB22.main(TestDB22.java:16)

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database using a program like SQL Developer or HeidiSQL? If so, how many rows are returned when you execute `select * from libids`;

Comment: yes.. 1 row is returned..!!

Comment: This is not a connectivity problem. It is a problem executing the query. You've connected successfully. Your own trace says so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm tempted to say that there's a bug in the driver. Make sure you're using the latest version.

If that doesn't work, try using a `PreparedStatement` instead (yes, I know that the query doesn't have any parameters, so please nobody downvote me :)

```
Statement st = con.prepareStatement("select * from libids");
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you **really** sure you have the right JDBC Driver.... OS390 os390 is pretty old, and was replaced in 2000 or something. Do you think you should be using the universal type 4 driver: `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver` instead of the os390 specific driver `COM.ibm.db2os390.sqlj.jdbc.DB2SQLJDriver`?